# XSLT Choose - testing attribute value

Tags: xslt

I'm strugling with a Choose statement and the corresponding Test-Clause.

If have the following XML (just an extract) which represents an datamodel exportet from Enterprise Architect as XMI:

```
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0" xmlns:EAUML="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/EAUML/1.0">       <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>      <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_F3388CFE_57A7_4d84_8866_3FB3AADE565A" name="Data Model - SQLServer2012" visibility="public">
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Artifact" xmi:id="EAID_B62341D4_41C6_4c83_A60A_4CA65C2E185E" name="Database SQLServer2012" visibility="public"/>
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_BA7676C5_40BC_4bd9_A0F5_F6B15E534E8E" name="Logical Model" visibility="public">
                    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_2DC36189_CCFB_40bf_A1CB_CD4FB08FE8B5" name="AnamneseStatus" visibility="public">
                        <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_9BBF5184_37F8_4729_9DC1_7ED3B4D8FC98" name="RCHIUNET05_ContextKey" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isReadOnly="false" isDerived="false" isOrdered="true" isUnique="false" isDerivedUnion="false">
                            <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000001_37F8_4729_9DC1_7ED3B4D8FC98" value="1"/>
                            <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000002_37F8_4729_9DC1_7ED3B4D8FC98" value="1"/>
                            <type xmi:idref="EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar"/>
                        </ownedAttribute>
                        <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_BC1F93D0_A7F4_474c_A27E_26D3ABCCFB7B" name="MRNCmpdId" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isReadOnly="false" isDerived="false" isOrdered="false" isUnique="true" isDerivedUnion="false">
                            <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000003_A7F4_474c_A27E_26D3ABCCFB7B" value="1"/>
                            <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000004_A7F4_474c_A27E_26D3ABCCFB7B" value="1"/>
                            <type xmi:idref="EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar"/>
                        </ownedAttribute>
..........
```

So with my XSL I will loop throug the relevant nodes and extract the tablenames and attributes. this works without problem. Now I need to translate the EA datatype into another datatype definition.

Lets say: EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar needs to become System.String

The XSL doing this looks like this (since there are other datatypes the Choose Statement will be longer than showed here):

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ownedAttribute[@xmi:type='uml:Property']">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="'Element Name=&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&quot; '"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@xmi:idref = 'EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Type=&quot;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'System.String'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&quot; '"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'MaxLength=&quot;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'400'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&quot; '"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@xmi:idref = 'EASQL_Server_2012_int'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Type=&quot;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'System.Int32'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&quot; '"/>
      </xsl:when>
......
```

Now my problem is, that it will not hit the test conditions and always run into the "otherwise" statement.

Does somebody see why the test condition is not working?

Thank you for any help on this.

Cheers
Sandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that instead of:

```
<xsl:when test="@xmi:idref = 'EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar'">
```

you want to do:

```
<xsl:when test="type/@xmi:idref = 'EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar'">
```

since in the partial example you have posted, `ownedAttribute` (which is your context node when you run this test) has no `xmi:idref` attribute, but its child element `type` does.

---

P.S. I don't know what you're doing overall, but I cringe whenever I see:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
```

This should never be necessary. If - as it seems - you're not outputting XML, set the output method to `text`. Then it's not necessary to disable output escaping.

Comment: hello michael

Just in this moment i realized what you wrote :) Thank you for your reply, works now :)